# jquery plugin for character count

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

as per code provide by Felix, i have made a html page for the character count script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.charlimit = function(options) {
            var def = {
            limit: 250,
                display: null
            };
            $.extend(def, options);
            var $display = $(def.display);

            $display.html(def.limit);

            this.bind('change keyup', function() {
                var l = $(this).val().length;
                $display.html(def.limit - l);
                if (l > def.limit) {
                    $(this).val(function(i, value) {
                        return value.substring(0, def.limit);
                    });
                    $display.html(def.limit - $(this).val().length);
                }
            });
            return this;
        };
    }(jQuery));


        //Plugin Call
        $('#message').charlimit({
            limit: 10,
            display: '#charCount'
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" tabindex="4" rows="4" cols="35"></textarea>
    <p class="character_limit">Character limit: <span id="charCount"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem i am facing is... when the character count becomes 0 and i press another key.. charcount will show -60 and the function(i, value) { ..... } gets inside the textarea.

Please check.

Thanks
LOkesh Yadav

Comment: I tried on jsfiddle, for me it works great...

Comment: Do the comments in the original post shed some light on your issue?

Comment: @Tim Post: As you can probably see, I answered the question here too, and it works (at least according to the information I have been given in the other comments). But somehow it feels not right to answer a question about my own code, having more information than other possible answerers have and potentially receiving reputation for that... for me this is more a "should be solved in the comments" question.

Comment: @Tim Post: It seems the issue is solved (in the comments of the original post).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a small syntax inaccuracy in there with the function declaration.. weird that this works, but maybe it's normal...

The last line of the function declaration is:

```
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

But should be:

```
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

**edit:** I didn't get an error in Firefox though, and it seemed to work fine, so this is probably not the culprit.

Comment: No, that does not make a difference... and my books say that the first way should be preferred ;)

Comment: It might not make a difference, but my way is also the way most people do it.. even jQuery does it that way. My way == best way

Comment: I checked what my book said. They use it because jsLint likes it more. I think it is just a matter of taste...